# getting error in browser when we run production build using Nextjs

Tags: build, next.js, lint, production

**getting error in browser when we run  production build using Nextjs**

```
  react_devtools_backend.js:4049 TypeError: Cannot set property 'length' of undefined
    at c (_app-eb48c4090f186b688116.js:1)
    at 5513.89ba65240e9cb87cd0f5.js:1
    at Ii (framework-336caa3f6419768205fe.js:1)
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (framework-336caa3f6419768205fe.js:1)
    at Wl (framework-336caa3f6419768205fe.js:1)
    at Oi (framework-336caa3f6419768205fe.js:1)
    at vi (framework-336caa3f6419768205fe.js:1)
    at framework-336caa3f6419768205fe.js:1
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (framework-336caa3f6419768205fe.js:1)
    at Wl (framework-336caa3f6419768205fe.js:1)
```

Comment: Please share your code by editing your question. This information is not sufficient.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

NextJS on build **pre-renders** all pages, this means it create static generation before serving it to client on stage called **hydration**

in this stage your data from API is not exist unless you are in client side.

don't do `array.length` before you check if it's defined first :

`array?.length` or `array && array.length`